# django admin not send html email, got plain text format instead

Tags: django

I've sent an email using django mail but the email sent as text format not html, I dont know why ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rKXe.png)). Please help me for this issue, thanks.

My admin:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

@admin.register(ParentsProfile)
class ParentsProfile(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('Father_Email','Fathers_Firstname' , 'Fathers_Middle_Initial', 'Fathers_Lastname', 'Request')
    ordering = ('Request',)
    search_fields = ('Request',)
    actions = ['Send_Email','Send_Email_Disapproved']

    def Send_Email(self, request, queryset):

        html_content = render_to_string('Homepage/email.html')
        for profile in queryset:
            send_mail(subject="Invite", message=html_content, from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                recipient_list=[profile.Father_Email])
```

My email template:

```
<img src="{% static 'unidalogo.png' %}" 
<p>Hi there</p>
<p>To: </p>
<p>Your Registration has been approved.</p>
<p>Please use this %s as your username and %s as your password</p>


<h2>REGISTRAR</h2>
```

**Updated question**:

I don't know how to connect the `profile.Father_Email` and `profile.Parent_Password` to html_template:

```
context = {
     'femail': profile.Father_Email, 
     'fpassword': profile.Parent_Password, 
}
html_message = render_to_string('Homepage/email.html', {"context":context)
```

The template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html  >
<head>

<title>Email</title>

</head>
<body>
     <img src="{% static 'unidalogo.png' %}" title="" style="height: 6.1rem;">UNIDA CHRISTIAN COLLEGES

<p>To: {{ femail }}</p>

<p>Your Registration has been approved.</p>
<p>Please use this {{ femail }} as your username and {{ fpassword }} as your password</p>
<br><br><br>


<h2>REGISTRAR</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use `html_message` instead of `message`

Comment: when i change it, I got this error  """"" send_mail() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'""""

Comment: As I remember, we have to use both, html_message will be used when we define it. If smtp lib check that it unable to send message as html format (html_message) then it will use text format (message). So try this:
`send_mail(subject="Invite", message=html_content, from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, recipient_list=[profile.Father_Email], html_message=html_content)`

Comment: yes , i already solve that error, but how to put the email of user to email.html? i already change the question

Comment: I think you already did. Create a context dictionary and then pass to `render_to_string` function as a context param

Comment: can you provide an example? i cant understand you, sorry.. noob here

Comment: Let me come up with an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem caused because you were not indicated `send_email` method to send your email as `text/html` content type. To provide that indicator, you have to provide `html_message` as a param of `send_email` method, follow [Django sending email docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/email/).

> html_message: If html_message is provided, the resulting email will be a multipart/alternative email with message as the text/plain content type and html_message as the text/html content type.

So it will be like this:

```py
for profile in queryset:
    html_content = render_to_string('Homepage/email.html')

    send_mail(subject="Invite", message=html_content, from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, recipient_list=[profile.Father_Email], html_message=html_content)
```

In case you want to pass a context into your template, you should create a dictionary and then pass it into `render_to_string` method via context param, like so:

```
for profile in queryset:
    context = {
        'email': profile.Father_Email,
        'password': profile.Parent_Password,
    }
    html_content = render_to_string('Homepage/email.html', context=context)

    send_mail(subject="Invite", message=html_content, from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, recipient_list=[profile.Father_Email], html_message=html_content)
```

and then on your template:

```
<p>To: {{ email }}</p>

<p>Your Registration has been approved.</p>
<p>Please use this {{ email }} as your username and {{ password }} as your password</p>
```

then your email will have `email` and `password` as your expected